# FacebookSDK 4 for iOS, FBSDKSharingContent with image, url and text?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I want to share (with publish_actions permission) some content. With native iOS sharing I'm able to put text, url and Image in the same share action.
How to do this in Facebook SDK 4?

This is what I'm using:

```
        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://something.com/image.png"];
        content.contentTitle = @"Share text";

        [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:weakSelf];
```

but problem is that this is just URL, not photo with thumbnail :|

Answer (score 0):

As posted in documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKShareLinkContent/

there is a "imageUR", "contentTitle",... :)

Comment: Do you have any issues with the title/description not showing up?  Mine are blank despite being set.  This is in the simulator.